# How get comments, likes, events that my news feed displays

Tags: facebook

1. How get my OWN comments, likes, actions just like my wall's recent activity shows for me or same way how my friend's feed work (it shows - "somebody likes a photo/video/anytng")?
2. Even more simple question: how to get all of news feed objects? Not only posts returned by API /posts, /home, /feed etc. And not only basic likes returned by API /likes. I need "friend1 commented ...", "friend2 likes photo", "friend3 and friend4 are now friends". 
   All of them.

I have fully checked access_token. Don't care about language/sdk.

Need your thoughts.

Comment: since my own answer was deleted by mod, i want to explain: there are no solution for this question (through major api issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible.  Very sad.
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=79350

Answer (score 0):

You should check out facebook Graph API Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

It has everything you're looking for.

Comment: I can understand what objects have 'likes', 'comments' fields, but it doesn't solve my problem.
/feed only gives Post objects.
So what type of object represents comments, likes and other actions?
I don't need likes of a given object /OBJ_ID/likes,
i need it from a wall.